# Python: Symmetric Difference Sorted List

Tags: python, list, sorting, numpy, set

Is there a good way to take the symmetric difference of two sorted lists in python and return a sorted list as a result.  My current version seems like a poor work around (convert to set, find symmetric difference, convert back to list, then resort)

Solutions with Numpy are fine the data type being sorted are ints.

```
sorted_symdiff(list1,list2):
""" Each list is already sorted, this seems inefficient """
    s1,s2 = set(list1),set(list2)
    diff = list(s1.symmetric_difference(s2))
    diff.sort()
    return diff
```

Comment: your current version `return`s `None`

Comment: @Chris_Rands right, I've edited to fix the error with the minimal example, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You must take advantage of the fact that the two sequences are sorted. You need to traverse both while comparing the elements one by one, and constructing the symmetric difference as you progress along each sequence.

If you are familiar with **big O notation**, the complexity of the following code is `O(m+n)` where `m = len(seq1)` and `n = len(seq2)`

The complexity of your algorithm is `O(log(m+n)*(m+n))` because you need to sort the resulting set.

> #### Caveat:
>
> **This answer is mostly an exercise to demonstrate how to take advantage of a sorted input.**
>
> In spite of a better complexity, for most inputs, its execution times 
>   are slower than the original poster's code that
>   uses python builtin `set` methods. In python, sets are implemented in c code
>   under the hood. Pure python will have a hard time beating that. Very
>   large input would be necessary to see any advantage (if any is at all
>   visible). This algorithm is the most efficient, but that does not mean
>   that it is faster - nor does it mean that you should use it: set
>   builtin methods are optimized and battle tested c code; they make for
>   code that is simpler to write, read, understand, debug, and maintain.

#### code:

```
def get_symmetric_difference(seq1, seq2):
    """
    computes the symmetric difference of unique elements of seq1 & seq2 
    as a new sorted list, without mutating the parameters.

    seq1: a sorted sequence of int
    seq2: a sorted sequence of int

    return: a new sorted list containing the symmetric difference 
            of unique elements of seq1 & seq2
    """

    if not seq1:
        symmetric_difference = seq2[:]
        return symmetric_difference
    if not seq2:
        symmetric_difference = seq1[:]
        return symmetric_difference

    symmetric_difference = []

    idx = 0
    jdx = 0  
    last_insert = None
    last_seen = None

    while idx < len(seq1) and jdx < len(seq2):
        s1 = seq1[idx]
        s2 = seq2[jdx]
        if s1 == s2:
            idx += 1
            jdx += 1
            last_seen = s1
        elif s1 < s2:
            if last_insert != s1 and last_seen != s1:
                symmetric_difference.append(s1)
                last_insert = s1
            idx += 1
        elif s2 < s1:
            if last_insert != s2 and last_seen != s2:
                symmetric_difference.append(s2)
                last_insert = s2
            jdx += 1

    if len(seq1[idx:]) > len(seq2[jdx:]):
        for elt in seq1[idx:]:
            if last_insert != elt and last_seen != elt:
                symmetric_difference.append(elt)
                last_insert = elt
                last_seen = elt
    else:
        for elt in seq2[jdx:]:
            if last_insert != elt and last_seen != elt:
                symmetric_difference.append(elt)
                last_insert = elt
                last_seen = elt

    return symmetric_difference
```

#### tests:

```
def test_get_symmetric_difference():

    seq1 = []
    seq2 = []
    assert get_symmetric_difference(seq1, seq2) == []

    seq1 = [1]
    seq2 = []
    assert get_symmetric_difference(seq1, seq2) == [1]

    seq1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    seq2 = [-2, -1, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    assert get_symmetric_difference(seq1, seq2) == [-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

    seq1 = [    -1, 1, 2, 3, 4,    6,       9,  22, 34]
    seq2 = [-2, -1,             5, 6, 7, 8, 19, 22,    43]
    assert get_symmetric_difference(seq1, seq2) == [-2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 19, 34, 43]

    seq1 = [-2, -1,             5, 6, 7, 8, 19, 22,    43]
    seq2 = [    -1, 1, 2, 3, 4,    6,       9,  22, 34]
    assert get_symmetric_difference(seq1, seq2) == [-2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 19, 34, 43]

    seq1 = [-2, -1, 0,            5,       22, 34]
    seq2 = [-2, -1,   1, 2, 3, 4,    6, 9, 22, 34]
    assert get_symmetric_difference(seq1, seq2) == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]

    seq1 = [-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 22, 34]
    seq2 = [-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 22, 34]
    assert get_symmetric_difference(seq1, seq2) == []

    seq1 = [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
    seq2 = [-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 22, 34]
    assert get_symmetric_difference(seq1, seq2) == [-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 22, 34]

    seq1 = [-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 22, 34]
    seq2 = [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
    assert get_symmetric_difference(seq1, seq2) == [-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 22, 34]

    seq1 = [-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 22, 34]
    seq2 = [-1, -1, 7, 7, 43, 43, 43]
    assert get_symmetric_difference(seq1, seq2) == [-2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 22, 34, 43]

    seq1 = [34, 34, 34, 34]
    seq2 = [7, 34]
    assert get_symmetric_difference(seq1, seq2) == [7]

    seq1 = [7, 34]
    seq2 = [34, 34, 34, 34]
    assert get_symmetric_difference(seq1, seq2) == [7]

    seq1 = [7, 34]
    seq2 = [7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
    assert get_symmetric_difference(seq1, seq2) == [34]

    seq1 = [7, 7, 7, 7, 34]
    seq2 = [7, 7]
    assert get_symmetric_difference(seq1, seq2) == [34]

    print("***all tests pass***")


test_get_symmetric_difference()
```

#### output:

```
***all tests pass***
```

Comment: This doesn't seem more efficient. In my test it's taking 5 times as long compared to the original code posted.

Comment: Yes... we are talking big O, not execution time. sets are implemented in `c code` under the hood, pure python will have a hard time beating that. Further, your input is surely too small to show anything; you will need very large input to see any advantage (if any is at all visible).  
This algorithm is the most efficient, but that does not mean it will be faster for the input you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying input size.  Actually all of my lists have at most 4 elements but I need to call this function many times

Comment: For most inputs, you are better off to stay with the implementation you have. 1- it is optimized and battle tested `c code`, and 2- it is simpler to write, read and understand. debug, and maintain. My answer is mostly an exercise that demonstrates how to take advantage of a sorted input.
As an exercise, you could implement the intersection of your lists in the same manner. (but keep with python builtins for your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Never trust a `set` to be sorted. Always sort after converting your `set` into `list` objects when you expect to return a sorted `list`. I'm uncertain about the behavior I've observed in the explanation below.**

<strike>You don't need to sort after converting back to a list since the lists already come sorted.</strike> Removing the extra sort will make it a bit more efficient.

If `list1` and `list2` are guaranteed to be sorted lists of positive `int` objects, the resulting `symmetric_difference` `set` seems to return sorted in Python 3.5. If `list1` and `list2` contains any negative `int` or `float` the results will need to be sorted again.

```
def sorted_symdiff(list1,list2):
    """ Each list is already sorted, this seems inefficient """
    s1,s2 = set(list1),set(list2)
    diff = list(s1.symmetric_difference(s2))
    return diff
```

Comment: I was under the impression that I could not be guaranteed that after converting to set the ordering would be preserved (especially after doing a set operation).  Is this a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: Sets are unsorted containers; there is no guarantee that the output will in any order.

Comment: I'm no expert but after doing a few tests comparing your function to the exact same function without the final sort, it seems they always return the same list in sorted order.

Comment: Your answer is still wrong - the result must be sorted to guarantee the ordering; please correct it so a casual reader will not get the false impression that it is okay to use it as it is.

Comment: You are correct. I was consistently getting sorted results while the inputs were of positive `int`s, but as soon as I added negatives and floats the results were returning unsorted. Will edit my answer.